# Intersect or union with a custom IEqualityComparer using Linq

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have 2 set of coolection in memory and i want to return one set based on the 2. My object have the following suructure:

```
class Item 
{
  public string key {get,set;}
  public int total1 {get;set;}
  public int total2 {get ;set;}
}
```

I would like to "union" them so that when the key on item form set 1 is equal to the key of an item from the set 2 , my union should return an item as follow:

```
item_union.Key= item1.key==item2.key;
item_union.total1= item1.total1 + item2.total1;
item_union.total2= item1.total2 + item2.total2;
```

can someone show me how i should build my custom equality compararer to obtain this result?

many thanks in advance

Comment: Will there only be one item with a particular key in each collection? What do you want to happen for items which don't have a corresponding key in the other collection?

Comment: In general the will be an item with the same key on both sides. When it is missing on one side, i just only use the one that is present. Many thanks

Comment: Okay, in that case I think my answer should be fine. No need for an intersection or a union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you *might* want a join, or you *might* just want to concatenate the collections, group by the key and then sum the properties:

```
// Property names changed to conform with normal naming conventions
var results = collection1.Concat(collection2)
                         .GroupBy(x => x.key)
                         .Select(g => new Item {
                                     Key = g.Key,
                                     Total1 = g.Sum(x => x.Total1),
                                     Total2 = g.Sum(x => x.Total2)
                                 });
```

Comment: Excellent, this means i do not need a custum IEqualityComaprer! That look very elegant. I will try that.